# Ubuntu 18.04: How to install Ruby1.9.1(ruby1.9.1-full, rubygems1.9.1, ruby1.9.1-dev)?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, ruby

I have followed below steps to install Ruby1.9.1 on ubuntu 18.04 but it is showing latest ubuntu version after installation:

Steps:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.9.1
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 1
```

Response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby1.9.1-full
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ruby1.9.1-full'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby1.9.1-full'
Ruby apt-get installation failed, make sure that apt is working correctly and try again
./install_opentest.sh: line 135: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rubygems1.9.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rubygems1.9.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'rubygems1.9.1'
rubygems apt-get installation failed, make sure that apt is working correctly and try again
./install_opentest.sh: line 135: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby1.9.1-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ruby1.9.1-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby1.9.1-dev'
```

Is it possible to install ruby1.9.1 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 2):

According to [search on http://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ruby1.9.1) Ruby 1.9.1 is available only for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

According to official [Ruby Maintenance Branches](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/) page 1.9.3 (as also 2.0.0, 2.1, 2.2) is **EOL**.

Consider to install supported version of [Ruby 2.5.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ruby) for your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt install ruby2.5 ruby2.5-dev
```

---

If you really need to install 1.9.1 - then compile it manually. But make sure that you want to use end-of-life and insecure version.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have dependency on ruby1.9.1 or ruby1.9.3. Is it possible for you to share steps to install ruby1.9.1-full, rubygems1.9.1, ruby1.9.1-dev, please? ruby1.9.3 will also work.

Comment: Any leads on how to configure ruby 1.9.1 or 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I do not know. Use search here or on internet.